# Max. Bluetooth Distance

Tags: android, bluetooth, communication

Simple Technical Questions :

1. What is the maximal Distance/Range where Bluetooth is Operationnal ?
2. Is there a way to Improve the Maximal Range ?
3. Is there a Protocol , to Transmit somes Data , who does Not need any Internet Connection , or Phone Network ?
4. Wifi Direct need an Access Point between Devices ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1.
Mostly Bluetooth devices have capacity of 10 meters to some specific range. It also depends on the capability of devices. Old devices have slow speed and less range in comparison to modern devices.

2.
Technically it's possible. You can achieve 1km (or better) range, But this is only possible between two transmitters/receivers. It is not possible to have 1km range with a Bluetooth device in my guess. Moreover, In many countries Bluetooth devices with output power stronger than 20dB (which is Class 1, 100m) are prohibited.

3.
**In your pc (An alternate answer)-**

Connect both computers to the same WiFi router.

Enable File and Printer Sharing on both computers. If you right click on a file or folder and choose to Share it, you will be prompted to turn on File and Printer Sharing. So, doing this to both the Shared Documents (all users) on the Windows XP machine and Public Documents (on the Windows 7 machine) would be a way to go.

Look for Available Network computers. Then copy and paste the data you want to transfer. For example... if you have a song on the Windows Machine shared Music directory, You would browse to that computer in the Network Connections available in Explorer on the Windows machine.
Browse that folder.. select the song..copy and then paste it wherever you wanted it to be.

You don't need to install third party software. Everything you need is to transfer files and folders between your computers is already there.

4.
No, maybe No.

Comment: Thanks you , this is not about File Transfert , but Audio Data , 10 Meters isnt Interesting , i have seen somes apps on Google Play that Claim to have 100 Meters Range

Comment: Also , i have seen that Wifi Direct does Not need an Access Point , what is the Maximal Range so ?

Comment: A general rule of thumb in home networking says that 802.11b and 802.11g WAPs and routers support a range of up to 150 feet (46 m) indoors and 300 feet (92 m) outdoors.

Comment: And about bluetooth range it is depended on milliwatt power, suppose if we say power in milliwatt is-> 100mW in decibels ->20 dBm. In this case you can gain over 100 meter of range.This is bluetooth's class1 in scientific words. That's what you need to read about.

Comment: Thanks you for your Answer , Yes , the Range various from many Sources , Here they say up to 656 feet http://www.pcworld.com/article/208778/Wi_Fi_Direct_vs_Bluetooth_4_0_A_Battle_for_Supremacy.html Wifi Direct look Promising and Better than Bluetooth